# Удалить те элементы массива, которые встречаются в нем ровно два раза в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Необходимо создать массив, и в нем удалить те элементы массива, которые встречаются ровно два раза

Comment: > создать массив из чего?

Comment: покажите ваш код

Comment: var masiv = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5];
masiv.forEach (function(write) {console.log(write);} );

Comment: Вы задавали этот вопрос вчера

Comment: Сейчас пытаюсь сделать тоже самое, но в JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf`, вызванная без второго параметра возвращает индекс *первого* вхождения искомого элемента в массив. Если же элемент текущей итерации - не тот, что будет найден методом `indexOf`, значит текущий элемент - дубль, и его включать в результирующий массив не нужно.

Следующий сниппет удаляет **все повторяющиеся** элементы массива (грубо говоря, довольно упрощенная реализация `.unique()`). **Оставлен по ошибке, т.к. я неправильно прочел условие изначально**, решение см. ниже.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, "str", "str2", "str"];

arr = arr.filter((item, i, source) => {
  // Если индекс элемента в массиве не равен индексу первого вхождения этого элемента в массив, то в результирующий массив этот элемент включать не надо
  return source.indexOf(item) === i;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Следующий сниппет **удаляет** все элементы, которых в массиве **ровно** 2 штуки.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, "str", "str2", "str"];

let toDelete = []; // элементы, которые нужно будет удалить сохраняем в отдальный массив, потому как изменять (а splice именно изменяет на месте) итерируемый массив - все равно что плевать против ветра
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let q = arr.filter(item => { // количество вхождение i-того элемента в массив
    return item === arr[i];
  }).length;
  
  if (q === 2) toDelete.push(arr[i]); // если вхождений - 2, то добавляем в список элементов, подлежащих удалению
}

toDelete.forEach(item => { // избавляемся от ненужных элементов
  arr.splice(arr.indexOf(item), 1);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: добавить 3 вхождения - и будет работать..
процитирую автора `удалить те элементы массива, которые встречаются ровно два раза`

Comment: Это не отвечает на вопрос "как удалить те элементы массива, которые встречаются в нем **ровно два раза**".

Comment: Верно, не заметил слово "ровно".

Comment: автор просто не тестил, он проверил с 2 вхождениями, вероятней всего..
ну и кроме этого, автору надо **удалить** эл-ты, которые встречаются 2 раза, это ни разу не решение.. но отметил, странно

Comment: @Bald потому что в таком случае до меня бы докопались по поводу того, что в задании фигурировало слово "удалить", а не "создать новый массив".

Comment: Гы, все равно докопаюсь: до эффективности)) Можно обойтись без прохода по всему массиву `n^2` лишних раз: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJgBRw?editors=0012

Comment: @yar85 так в ответ напишите, в чем проблема. UPD А, точно, не заметил, что дубликат :)